# How to do parenthesis balancing using scala, recursion ,one function and one parameter for the function?

Tags: scala, recursion

I am builing a little method for parenthesis balancing using scala and recursion.

I came out this code which surprisingly doesn't work.

```
object Test{

def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean=
{
  var opening_index: Int = -1
  var  closing_index: Int = -1
  opening_index = chars.indexOf('(')
  closing_index = chars.indexOf(')')
  println(opening_index)
  println(closing_index)
  if ( chars.size == 0 ) true


  if ((opening_index == -1) & (closing_index== -1))
    {
      true
    }
  if (closing_index> -1 & opening_index> -1)
    {
      if (closing_index< opening_index) return(false)
      else
      {
        balance(chars.filter(_!=chars(closing_index)).filter(_!=chars(opening_index)))
      }
    }
  else
    return (false)
}


  val lst:List[Char] = List('(',')' ,'3','4')
  balance(lst)
}
```

I am aware that there are other similar posts but I am more interested in using this approach than the other ones.

Comment: Your `filter` deletes all parens in the first step. What did you even try to do here? The approach as a whole cannot work, because you are not passing any stack (or at least `Int`) that tells you the current nesting level.

Comment: Yes I see. I was mistaken. What I wanted to do was to remove the the first occurence of ( and the first occurence of ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably wanted to filter by index, not by character. As it is, your code erases all parentheses in the first round.

This here works with `zipWithIndex`, and compares the index with `opening_index` and `closing_index`:

```
def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {
  val opening_index = chars.indexOf('(')
  val closing_index = chars.indexOf(')')

  if ( chars.size == 0 ) {
    true 
  } else if ((opening_index == -1) && (closing_index== -1)) {
    true
  } else if (closing_index > -1 && opening_index > -1) {
    if (closing_index < opening_index) {
      false
    } else {
      balance(
        chars.zipWithIndex.filterNot{ 
          case (c, i) => i == opening_index || i == closing_index
        }.map(_._1)
      )
    }
  } else {
    false
  }
}

println(balance("()34".toList))
println(balance("()34)".toList))
println(balance("(x)(y(z))".toList))
println(balance("(x)(y(z)".toList))
```

Output:

```
true
false
true
false
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main (functional) problems with this code.

Firstly, this test does nothing because the result is thrown away

```
if ((opening_index == -1) & (closing_index== -1))
{
  true
}
```

You probably meant `return true`

Secondly, the recursive call is wrong

```
balance(chars.filter(_ != chars(closing_index)).filter(_ != chars(opening_index)))
```

These two calls to `filter` are removing ***all*** the parentheses from the list, so the call to `balance` will always succeed even if the rest of the list is unbalanced.
You probably want to use three `slice` calls to remove the specific parentheses at `opening_index` and `closing_index`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below solution to check balance parenthesis.

```
object Driver extends App{

  def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean=
  {
    if (chars.mkString("").length() == 0) {
      return true;
    }
    if (chars.mkString("").contains("()")) {
      return balance(chars.mkString("").replaceFirst("\\(\\)", "").toCharArray.toList);
    }

    if (chars.mkString("").contains("[]")) {
      return balance(chars.mkString("").replaceFirst("\\[\\]", "").toCharArray.toList);
    }
    if (chars.mkString("").contains("{}")) {
      return balance(chars.mkString("").replaceFirst("\\{\\}", "").toCharArray.toList);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }


  println(balance(List('(','{','}')))

  println(balance(List('(','{','}',')')))

}
```

Comment: If you pass parameter as string then you can remove some code from my solution.

Comment: That doesn't work.   `println(balance(List('(', '3', ')')))` gives `false`. This would work only if there were nothing to put in the brackets, which makes it a Dyck-language checker, with a very slow implementation.